# не удаляется html элемент при нажатии на кнопку через jQuery но стили применяются к кнопке. кто может подсказать?

Tags: jquery

```
    $(function(){
    $('.btn')

    .click(function(){
        $('.block-left__text').remove();
    })
    .css({
        'margin': '20px',
        'color': 'indigo'
    });
});

<div class="container">
    <div class="block-left">
        <h2 class="block-left__title">Список дел:</h2>
        <p class="block-left__text">Список пуст...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.block-left -->
    <div class="block-right">
        <h2 class="block-right__text">Добавить новое дело</h2>
        <form action="" class="block-right__form">
            <div class="form-title">
                <p class="form-title__title">* Название</p>
                <input type="text" class="form-title__text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-description">
                <p class="form-description__title">* Описание</p>
                <textarea name="" maxlength="400" class="form-description__text" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn">Добавить дело</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.block-right -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я могу подсказать.

---

У Вас страница перегружается.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn')
    .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.block-left__text').remove();
    })
    .css({
      'margin': '20px',
      'color': 'indigo'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-left">
    <h2 class="block-left__title">Список дел:</h2>
    <p class="block-left__text">Список пуст...</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.block-left -->
  <div class="block-right">
    <h2 class="block-right__text">Добавить новое дело</h2>
    <form action="" class="block-right__form">
      <div class="form-title">
        <p class="form-title__title">* Название</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-title__text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-description">
        <p class="form-description__title">* Описание</p>
        <textarea name="" maxlength="400" class="form-description__text" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="btn">Добавить дело</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- /.block-right -->
```

или

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Добавить дело</button>
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, ответ или очень помог)